# PHP problem with undefinied errors variable

Tags: php

I got problem with "Undefined variable: errors in transaction.php on line 2"

If i try create template site with $errors variable it should give $error array in required transaction.php, but it doesnt, how it should be given to this transaction.php to get it work?

index.php

```
    function checkTransaction(){
            if(!empty($_POST['code'])){
                return true;
            }
            return [
                'code' => false
            ];
        }

        function renderTransactionResult($errors){
            $getTemplate = new Template('transaction', [
                'errors' => $errors
            ]);

            echo $getTemplate;
        }


        $transactionid = htmlspecialchars($_POST['search']);
        $transactionrows = $main->CheckNumRowsTransaction($transactionid);


        if($transactionrows === 1){
            $errors = checkTransaction($_POST);

            renderTransactionResult($errors);
        }else{
        $errors = [
            'transaction' => false
        ];

        renderTransactionResult($errors);
        }
```

GetTransaction.php

```
<?php
    Class Template{
        public function __construct($template, $vars){
            $this->template = $template;
            $this->vars = $vars;
            
        }
        public function __toString(){
            foreach ($this->vars as $name => $value){
                $name = $value;
            }
            unset($name, $value);
            ob_start();
            require('templates/' . $this->template . '.php');
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
    }
```

transaction.php

```
<?php
    if(is_array($errors)){
        echo 'something';
    }else{
        echo 'something';
    }
?>
```

Comment: the problem is `transactions.php` has no idea about `$errors` as it hasn't been defined in the scope of that file.

Comment: i know, but when is required from other file "index.php"(where got this $errors variable)  evokes function in "GetTransaction.php" and required this template, so i think that should work but it doesnt

Comment: Explain what that foreach loop is supposed to do. (Pretty sure it doesn’t do what you intended.)

Comment: Instead of your foreach loop and your unset (which aren't correct either way), use [extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) like this: `extract($this->vars);`.

Comment: @magnus eriksson that work, thanks for help you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate variables, they have a certain scope in which the variable is known. I don't see how you're loading the files, but am assuming you want the logic of transaction.php to happen when visiting index.php. To achieve this, either make transaction.php into a class that takes $errors as a constructor variable, instantiate it and call the method:

[transaction.php]

```
class Transaction
{
    private $errors;
    public function _construct($errors)
    {
         $this->errors = $errors;
    }

    public function handleErrors()
    {
        if(is_array($errors))
        {
            echo 'something';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'something';
        }
    }
}
```

[getTransaction.php]

```
Class Template
{
    public function __construct($template, $vars)
    {
        $this->template = $template;
        $this->vars = $vars;
        $transaction = new Transaction($vars); //instantiates your class
        $transaction->handleErrors(); //calls the method
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        foreach ($this->vars as $name => $value)
        {
            $name = $value;
        }
        unset($name, $value);
        ob_start();
        require('templates/' . $this->template . '.php');
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Or make transaction.php into a function that you define and call in index.php:
[index.php]

```
function checkTransaction()
{
    if(!empty($_POST['code']))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return [
        'code' => false
    ];
}

function handleErrors($errors)
{
    if(is_array($errors))
    {
        echo 'something';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'something';
    }
}

function renderTransactionResult($errors)
{
    $getTemplate = new Template('transaction', [
        'errors' => $errors
    ]);

    echo $getTemplate;
}

$transactionid = htmlspecialchars($_POST['search']);
$transactionrows = $main->CheckNumRowsTransaction($transactionid);


if($transactionrows === 1)
{
    $errors = checkTransaction($_POST);

    renderTransactionResult($errors);
}
else
{
    $errors = [
        'transaction' => false
    ];

    renderTransactionResult($errors);
}
```

Note that I did not review your code on functionality, efficiency or security, but only formulated an answer to solve your scoping issue.

[Check out the manual for more info on variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)